# UnauthorizedAccessException while accessing registry key in domain network

Tags: c#, .net, registry, authorization, windows-users

I want to set value for a registry key. When I try to use SetValue method it throws  **UnauthorizedAccessException** exception, that says:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

This is my code:

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser
            .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE")
            .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
            .OpenSubKey("Windows")
            .OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
            .OpenSubKey("Run", true);

if (key.GetValue("MyKey") == null)
{
    key.SetValue("MyKey", localPath, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```

Comment: did u try by running your program as an administrator account?  right click ur executable cmd or winForm and run it as an administrator.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes, I've tried it! but nothing is changed :s

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try with `Registry` Class??

below is the working code from my live server.

```
        RegistryKey registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"software\newclient", true);            

        if (registry == null)
        {
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"software\newclient");
            registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"software\newclient", true);
        }

        if (registry.GetValue("CreatedTime")==null)
        {
            registry.SetValue("CreatedTime", "1/1/1900 00:00 PM");
        }

        if (registry.GetValue("CurrentVersion") == null)
        {
            registry.SetValue("CurrentVersion", "0.0.0.0");
        }

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(registry.GetValue("CreatedTime").ToString()) != Convert.ToDateTime(arr[1]))
        {
            /*
             * other code snippet
             *
             */
            registry.SetValue("CurrentVersion",arr[0]);
            registry.SetValue("CreatedTime", arr[1]);

            return true;
        }

        registry.Close();
        return false;
```

Comment: still getting the same error?? well then i am not sure.. its the correct and working code from my live project

Answer (score 0):

OpenSubKey can take 2 parameters, one of which is the subkey path, and the second can take the writable (bool) parameter

```
using(RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environmen", true))
     {
         key.SetValue(saveValue, RegSelect);
     }
```